# Authentication fail with okhttp + ssl + basic auth

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm using okhttp3 to request some web service through SSL + basic auth using the following client builder:

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
    .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    })
    .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
            String credential = Credentials.basic("myuser", "mypassword");
            return response.request().newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", credential)
                    .build();
        }
    })
    .build()
```

then I run the request with

```
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
requestBuilder.url(url);
Request request = requestBuilder.build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
```

and I get a 403 (access denied).

I tried using cURL and I get authenticated correctly.

I set a breakpoint in the `authenticate`  function, and it seems that it is not even called.

If I set the header directly in `requestBuilder`, i.e.

```
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
requestBuilder.url(url);
String credential = Credentials.basic("myuser", "mypassword");
requestBuilder.header("Authorization", credential).build();
Request request = requestBuilder.build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
```

it works.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you find a reason for this issue?  I am facing a similar situation